# "Windows is Configuring" Dialog During Program Use on a Terminal Server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-installer, terminal-services

I am encountering a particularly annoying issue in terminal server environments where Windows will throw "Windows is configuring" dialog boxes similar to Microsoft Office when trying to perform functions within out software. I suspected it might have had something to do with the way the program was installed, but even using the "Install Programs on a Terminal Server" feature described in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742815%28v=ws.10%29.aspx had no effect. My last thought was it might be something to do with user profiles, but I haven't been able to determine anything to that end. Has anyone encountered this with other programs and figured out how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: Something triggers repair installation: either a key file or a key registry value is missing, perhaps in user's profile. Windows log should contain a hint why MSI repairs your installation. Doesn't it happen if you use your app on regular desktop?

Comment: No, we only see it in Terminal Server environments, likely because the installation files, along with any other temp files, reside in the local APPDATA folders of a regular workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you've installed some per-user files or registry settings in a per-machine installation. For each user, these will have to be repaired and the installation process run again.

If you look in the Event log you'll be able to identify the problematic component that is causing the repair to be triggered. Also it would be worth investigating the log files from when you built the MSI - chances are that during MSI validation a warning about this would have been triggered.

Comment: Possible, though each user was cycling through the configuration dialog multiple times. The only time I've ever seen this before was with some Office installations requiring additional files. At the moment we're not getting it to occur again, but the only changes I made was I used the RDP Installer to deploy another MSI we use for some additional libraries, and I made changes to the TS configuration to not delete temp directories on session exit. That seems to be working for now.